# How to display the data assetCode in ag grid (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

how to display the data assetCode in children `headerName`?

the data being display is based on the length of `rowData` and I'm trying to do is display the `assetCode` in `children` `headerName`.
which the output should be.

***January*** then has child
***PRN | PRN1 | PRN2***

Where you will see the output below.

here's the code for the

***list.component.ts***

```
this.rowData.push(
      {
        'code': 'Machine 1', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-18 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 1', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-19 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 2', 'assetCode': 'PRN 1', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-20 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 3', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-21 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 4', 'assetCode': 'PRN 1', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-22 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 5', 'assetCode': 'PRN 2', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-23 00:00:00'
      },
    );

    this.rowData = this.rowData.filter((item: any) => {
      return format(item.date, 'YYYY') === param;
    });

    const newData: any = [];
    this.rowData.forEach((x: any) => {
      const existing = newData.find((y: any) => format(y.date, 'YYYY-MM') === format(x.date, 'YYYY-MM')
        && y.assetCode === x.assetCode && y.code === x.code);
      if (existing) {
        existing.assetCount += existing.assetCount;
      } else {
        newData.push(x);
        this.rowData = newData;
      }
    });

    this.columnDefs.push(
      {
        'headerName': 'Style/Machine',
        'field': 'code',
        'pinned': 'left',
        'lockPosition': true
      }
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      const record = {
        'headerName': this.monthNames[i].monthName,
        'children': [
          {
            'headerName': 'Total', 'columnGroupShow': 'closed',
            'valueGetter': ' ', 'headerClass': '', 'cellStyle': {}
          }
        ]
      };

      this.rowData.forEach((key: any) => {
        if (this.monthNames[i].monthName === format(key.date, 'MMMM')) {
          record.children.push(
            {
              'headerName': key.code, 'columnGroupShow': 'open', 'headerClass': 'header-text-center',
              'cellStyle': { 'justify-content': 'center' },
              'valueGetter': key.assetCount ? key.assetCount.toString() : null
            }
          );
        }
      });
      this.columnDefs.push(record);
    }
    }
```

***output***
[image]

***it should be like this***

[image]

thanks in Advance

Comment: what output in object format you want share that one

Comment: @SaurabhYadav the ```assetCount``` for example ```newData1``` when ```machine 1``` have ```assetCount: 2``` also have ```assetCode: PRN```. then ```newData2``` has ```assetCode: PRN```. if ```newData1``` ```assetCode: PRN```  ```=``` ```newData2``` ```assetCode: PRN``` it will place the ```newData1``` ```assetCount: 2``` will place to the ```PRN```.